# Deploying to TURN servers without call draining

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn

We currently have a fleet of TURN servers deployed all over the world, and it can take quite a while to deploy new software to each of them. We've been trying to brainstorm ideas of deploying to TURN without draining the calls (i.e. move the calls from one TURN server to another live).

Does TURN support this sort of thing out of the box? For example, could we use the `STUN Error 300 - alternate-server` mechanism to get clients off of `TURN server A` and onto `TURN server B` during a live call?

Our current setup is `client <-> TURN <-> TURN  <-> client`.

We were also thinking that perhaps we could use the multi-peer functionality to split the stream and then sort of shuffle around the TURN servers. Sort of like a rolling deployment.

The last option is to code a custom SFU in Rust or something that supports our every use case. However, we would have to therefore update the client code, which at this point seems... well difficult :).

The clients are using PJSIP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TURN doesn't support this out of the box. The closest thing you can do is to modify the server to return alternate-server error the next time the clients attempts to refresh an allocation and then have the client handle that and do an ICE restart (assuming the client does ICE) with the new server.

Comment: Do you know how much downtime a client would experience during that renegotiation? Ideally, we would want to do it without them really noticing it happened.

Comment: It depends on the client implementation. ICE restarts (maybe only in webrtc) follow a "make before break" pattern where the new connection is established before the old one is discarded. I have no experience with pjsip however.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. This may be what we have to do if that's the case...

I was thinking:

1. Create a new fleet of the same size with the new software.
2. Move everyone over to the new fleet.
3. Kill the old fleet when there are no more calls remaining.

Comment: Yes. The main problem is how to convey that "we are draining" from the server to the client and responding with a 300 error on the next allocation refresh (which typically happens every 10 minutes, depending on the client and/or server) seems like the best way to go.

Comment: Is it possible to add a peer during a live call? For example, could I tell the client to send to not only `Peer A`, but also `Peer B` as well? In this case, both peers would be other TURN servers. Im trying really hard to not write an SFU from scratch here haha

Comment: TURN servers are not SFUs, in particular they do not decrypt media. But you're diverging from the question.